# Plotting this function $x^2+(1-x)^8\sin(1/(1-x))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, graphing-functions

I need help to plot the function $x^2+(1-x)^8\sin\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$ in the range $[0.5,1)$ together with the functions $x^2+(1-x)^8$ and $x^2-(1-x)^8$.

As $x$ approaches $1$ the first function is supposed to oscillate between the two other functions, but I am not able to capture this effect in a plot. The reason for this is that the absolute value of $(1-x)^8$ becomes very small. Are you able to plot these three functions and observe the oscillation?

For those interested in the motivation of this function: I wanted a function that does not behave nicely, but that is positive, has a positive first derivative, and has a positive second derivative on the range $[0.5, 1]$(here we require that the funciton value is $1$ at $x=1$.)

Comment: The way you set it up it is not supposed to have wild oscillations, because the $ O(u^8)$ term drowns out the oscillations. Look at $u^n \sin 1/u$ for $n=0,1,2$ to get some intuition.

Comment: @BenjaminWang For the functions you mention I am able to see the oscillations if I just zoom in close enough in the y-axis.

Comment: @PeterForeman An infinite number of oscillations.

Comment: @user394334 How can the function oscillate and yet have a positive first and second derivative?

Comment: @PeterForeman It is meant as an oscillation between the functions $x^2+(1-x)^8$ and  $x^2-(1-x)^8$.

Comment: Try to plot it between 0.5 and 0.2. Do you use GeoGebra?

Comment: Try 0.6 to 0.8. ignore the previous one.

Comment: Why power of 4 will not suffice?

Comment: @Moti I tried graphing it like you said in GeoGebra, but I wasnæt able to see the effect. The reason I chose power of 8 was I made a rough estimate so the second-derivative would be positive.

Comment: Try to use log() function on y

Comment: You are right - for reason not yet clear to me the oscillation are not presented as expected.

Comment: When you use it with GeoGebra you need multiply the angle by 2$\pi$ and than you see the oscillation - use range 0.3 to 0.9